# In need of JPEG test images with exif thumbnaill in none-compressed TIFF format

Tags: testing, jpeg, thumbnails, exif

I know most (>>99%?) JPEG thumbnails embedded in APP1 EXIF are JPEG compressed (Still in TIFF format). But there is the possibility of a none-compressed TIFF format thumbnail. The problem is I just couldn't find any such images to test with.

I would appreciate it very much if someone can provide a link to such a test image.

Ok, let's do it the other way around: I created one of such image but not sure if it conforms to the spec and I hope to see if any software there can recognize and extract the thumbnail from it.

Here is the link to the testing sample image:
[sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5lp97q8q0hzjfm/thumbnail-inserted.jpg)

Comment: Your sample looks fine to me. :-) Not sure if you really need to specify `PlanarConfiguration: 1` as it is the default, and my other samples has `XResolution`, `YResolution` and `ResolutionUnit` specified (but unsure if they are mandatory).

Comment: @haraldK: Thanks for the testing. The testing image was created with some changes on top of another piece of code. But I believe I can get ride of PlanarConfiguration. As for the resolution. Personally I think it would really matters when printing is involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a couple in my project here: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master/imageio/imageio-jpeg/src/test/resources/jpeg

At least `exif-rgb-thumbnail-bad-exif-kodak-dc210.jpg` and `exif-rgb-thumbnail-sony-d700.jpg` should contain RGB (uncompressed) thumbnails in the Exif segment. The first one really has a non-compliant Exif (bad TIFF) segment though.

Comment: You are amazing. I got the three images with names starting with exif-rgb-thumbnail-. They all work for me. One is JPEG compressed and the other two are "pure" TIFF.

Answer (score 0):

Sample images for testing Exif metadata [Github repo](https://github.com/ianare/exif-samples)